# Is there a way to show the faulty code line instead of the memory address when a runtime error occurs in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

See the Question in the title:

> Runtime error 201 at $0000000100001D42   $0000000100001D42

Is there a way to show the faulty code line instead of the memory address?

Thanks for the Help

Comment: Can you add some more information to this question? What is erroring (is it VSCode that has an error or is it your application)? If this is your application, what language are you using? The more details the better answer you will get.

Comment: The application produces the error, language is pascal.
Edit: Sorry for not giving enough information in the first place, im a programming beginner and its hard to know what info is important.

Comment: I just put in an edit to add pascal to the tags. Also, if you have some code that you can provide as an example it will be able to help the pascal community.

Comment: The question is not about my code, its the error in VSCode. Im just trying to figure if there is a way to change a setting im not aware of to show the faulty line that produces the runtime error instead of the memory address.

Comment: Aren't you using any extension? For example [Pascal language support for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alefragnani.pascal). There are some more extensions for Pascal available in VSCode.

Comment: I do use extensions but the problem has nothing to do with my code(i think) it's the error message VSCode produces, im looking for a setting or an extension that outputs the line of code that produces the runtime error instead of the memory address were it occurs. I'm not searching a fix for my code.
EDIT: a letter

Comment: Yeah thats what i was looking for. Thanks alot! EDIT: How do i flag your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, when a run-time error occurs, you are presented with a list of addresses that represent the call stack backtrace, i.e. the addresses of all procedures that were invoked when the run-time error occurred.

This list is not very informative, so there exists a unit that generates the file names and line numbers of the called procedures using the addresses of the stack backtrace. This unit is called lineinfo.

You can use this unit by giving the `-gl` option to the compiler. The unit will be automatically included. It is also possible to use the unit explicitly in your uses clause, but you must make sure that you compile your program with debug info.

When compiled with `-gl`, the following output is generated:

```
Runtime error 255 at 0x0040BDE5  
  0x0040BDE5  GENERATEERROR255,  line 6 of testline.pp  
  0x0040BDF0  GENERATEANERROR,  line 13 of testline.pp  
  0x0040BE0C  main,  line 17 of testline.pp  
  0x0040B7B1
```

This is more understandable than the normal message. Make sure that all units you use are compiled with debug info, because if they are not, no line number and filename can be found.